# os.environ['PATH'] is not same as system path showed by echo $PATH

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, path

```
echo $PATH 
>> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/tms/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/bin:/var/home/root/bin:
```

But while getting the path from `os.environ['PATH']` it is returning only `:` which does not have other paths in it.

`'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'`

Does `os.environ['PATH']` show the path from where python script was started?
Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you modify your PATH in anyway beforehand? They should both be giving the same path..

Comment: No haven't modified any path.

Comment: How are you updating the PATH in your ~/.bashrc file (or wherever you do that)? Are you using `export`?

Comment: By whom and how is the python script started?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to find your $PATH in python:

```
import os #Imports the OS library

Path = os.environ.get("PATH") #Gets the path

print("Path:" + Path)  #Prints it out
```